# Is source code off an app avilble for the user?

Tags: tidesdk

If i write an desktop app in tidesdk or tide kit will it be possible for users to read my source code, just like from ordinary web page or not ?

Comment: How are you providing your application? Are you handing over your source code? Is it compiled into some executable? All of this depends on language your using and how you are packaging it, provide us more info... looking at their homepage, it seems tidesdk creates "EXECUTABLES" so you don't have to worry about people seeing your messy messy code.

Comment: Well, that was rather a general question, i don't have any app yet, but at some point i might begin to write commercial desktop app, and in such case i would prefer that users couldn't access its source code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the user knows where to look. It's not viewable by right clicking the window and selecting source, but if they browse to the install directory, all the HTML / related files are there in broad daylight.

You could come up with some strategies to protect them, either using encryption or just providing a bootstrapper application which downloads the rest of the source from a server on startup or something like that...but if it's a huge concern of yours you're probably better off using a different platform.